# Trouble with uniqueidentifier column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I just started working with SQL Server and I have some troubles with adding values to a table with a column of type `uniqueidentifier`.

The table consists of:

```
ID (uniqueidentifier), CODE (nchar(5)), COUNTRY_CODE(nchar(2)), NAME(nchar30)
```

I tried adding values from Excel and CSV files, basically they look like this:

```
DEBE,DE,Berlin
```

I could not load it, always have some errors with this ID field.

When i try to add values manually like:

```
INSERT INTO [Portfolio].[dbo].[Regions](CODE, COUNTRY_CODE, NAME) 
VALUES ('DEBE', 'DE', 'Berlin');
```

It says:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table
>   'Portfolio.dbo.Regions'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Of course when I add an `id` column and a number, I get info that int is incompatible with `uniqueidentifier`.

I even tried creating a temp table (with `id` as an `INT` instead of `uniqueidentifier`) and copying values from it into this (without `ID` column, its supposed to generate automatically)

Only thing I can think of is that `ID` column is not creating values for it automatically and I don't know how to solve this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uniqueidentifier is a special type you can use to generate GUID. Is 16 byte long and is not incremented automatically as the Identity columns. You need to use Convert or Cast clause in order to get the correct uniqueidentifier from a varchar, if it exceeds the 16bytes it will be truncated.

Use NewID() to generate a new uniqueidentifier.

[Maybe this link can help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, use NewID() to create an identifier.

When you are in the design mode for the table, NewID() can be placed in the 'Default Value or Binding' slot. This means that for any new record that you insert into the table (such as CODE, COUNTRY_CODE, NAME), a Unique Identifier will be created.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for is an Identity field.  The UniqueIdentifier field is used for storing GUID's.

Change the field type to int and then change it's Identity Specification to 'Yes".

The other solution would be to pass the ID field your own GUID from code.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer, but it may help someone, go to you sql table design mode, 
select your required table's attribute, here in detail tab (down to table) you'll see a property 
RowGuid --> Yes (make sure to turn it to yes).

Cheers :)